# NGRX Effect not filtering action / functions inside pipe are executed

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

I have an effect, but the mergeMap after the first switchMap inside it gets triggered without firing action of type GetPackageCalendar

```
@Effect()
  loadCalendar$ = this.actions$
    .pipe(
      ofType(fromActions.GetPackageCalendar),
      switchMap(() => this.store.select(selectRouterState)),
      mergeMap(
        (state: RouterStateUrl) => this.store.select(selectCalendarParams).pipe(
          switchMap((calParams) => this.getPackageCalendar(state, calParams)),
          //this gets executed
        ),
      ),
      map((calendar: CalendarRS) => new fromActions.SetPackageCalendar(calendar)),
    );
```

`

What is happening?

I want to select two values from the store and pass them as parameters to `getPackageCalendar`

Answer (score 1):

My guess is because of the `store select` part in your first  `switchMap`. It keeps subscribing to the `GetPackageCalendar` after first call. In this case, you only want to select the store value for one time. so include a `take(1)` to auto unsubscribe, after execution.

```
@Effect()
loadCalendar$ = this.actions$
  .pipe(
    ofType(fromActions.GetPackageCalendar),
    switchMap(() => {
      // take one only
      const obs$ = this.store.select(selectRouterState).pipe(take(1));
      return obs$;
    }),
    ...
  );
```

Comment: still gets executed with this approach

Comment: can u share ur redux log?

Comment: also your code. Good to have a working demo on stackblitz.com to troubleshoot

Answer (score 0):

> I want to select two values from the store and pass them as parameters to getPackageCalendar

Use withLatestFrom for that

```
@Effect()
loadCalendar$ = this.actions$.pipe(
  ofType(fromActions.GetPackageCalendar),
  withLatestFrom(
    this.store.select(selectRouterState),
    this.store.select(selectCalendarParams)
  ),
  mergeMap(([state, calParams]) => this.getPackageCalendar(state, calParams)),
  map((calendar: CalendarRS) => new fromActions.SetPackageCalendar(calendar))
);
```